# Keeping an image in its location when animation occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of images and when you click on an image all the images but the one clicked move down. My problem is when I do this the image remaining is pulled to the top left. I think it's because I'm removing the images so the remaining one is not considered the only one so it's placed in position 1 of the grid

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#grid li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().animate({opacity: 0, top:'15px'},1000);
  $(this).siblings().fadeOut(function() {
     });
  });   

$('#hidden').click(function() {
  $('#grid li img').animate({width:'339px',height:'211px'});
  $('#grid li').siblings().fadeIn();
  $('#grid li').siblings().animate({opacity: 1, top:'0px'},1000);
       });
   });
```

HTML

```
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul id="grid">   
     <li><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="5.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="6.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="7.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="8.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="9.jpg"><span>some text></a></li>
      </ul></div>
 <div id="hidden">
```

CSS

```
 ul#grid {
  list-style: none;
  top: 0;
  margin: 60px auto 0;
  width: 1200px; 
   }

 #grid li span {
  color: white;
  display:block;
  bottom:250px;
  position:relative;
  width:180px;
  }

 #grid li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 40px 75px 0px;
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/13/)

Comment: Your thoughts about your problem are correct, but what do you like to achieve instead?

Comment: I'd like to keep the image in it's original location. I tried some jquery for getting the position of the current image and using it to keep it there but things turned wild; images flying all over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to not use fadeOut() cause it sets display:none and that is why your image gets moved.

```
$('#grid li').click(function() {
  // $(this).siblings().css("position","relative");
  $(this).siblings().animate({opacity: 0, top:'15px'},1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
      $('#grid li img').animate({width:'339px',height:'211px'});
  });
 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/16/)

Comment: problem you can still click the images the are not being displayed

Comment: For example use a class to set them clickable or not. http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/17/

Answer (score 1):

Prototype has a method called `absolutize` <kbd>[**Link**](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Element/absolutize/index.html)</kbd>, which should work for your scenario. Since you are using jQuery you might want to have a look at this plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.absolutize = function()
{
  return this.each(function(){
    var element = jQuery(this);
    if (element.css('position') == 'absolute'){
        return element;
    }

    var offsets = element.offset();
    var top = offsets.top;
    var left = offsets.left;
    var width = element[0].clientWidth;
    var height = element[0].clientHeight;

    element._originalLeft = left - parseFloat(element.css("left") || 0);
    element._originalTop = top - parseFloat(element.css("top") || 0);
    element._originalWidth = element.css("width");
    element._originalHeight = element.css("height");

    element.css("position", "absolute");
    element.css("top", top + 'px');
    element.css("left", left + 'px');
    element.css("width", width + 'px');
    element.css("height", height + 'px');
    return element;
  });
}
```

Source: <kbd>[**Link**](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2008/09/11/absolutize-for-jquery/)</kbd>

Use this to *freeze* the size / position of your target element, before the dom changes occur:

```
$('#grid li').absolutize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try using Jquery animate to simply fade their opacity to 0. What fadeout actually does is fade the opacity to zero, then once it's at zero, it sets "display: none" so that the object disappears. You simply want to only do the former!  Something like $('myobjects').animate({opacity: 0}, slow); Hopefully my syntax is correct there. Cheers!

Comment: Matty-d thanks that works but the you can still click the images that have gone to opacity 0 and I can't click the background to bring everything back

Comment: Ah yes, Then after the animation occurs, give the objects visibility: hidden. It will still take up space, but it won't be there for the user to click!

Comment: I tried it but i doesn't seem to work, I'm sure it's my code     $(this).siblings().css("visibility", "hidden")};

Comment: Hmm that seems right, Maybe it's not happening after your animation or something? Sorry I don't know!